# In PHP, MySQL throws Commands out of sync error, while trying to use '$mysqli->multi_query'

Tags: php, mysql

In PHP, while I try to use $mysqli->multi_query second time, it throws me following error.

I looked at MySQL manual, and similar questions asked at SO, all suggest using 
either `$mysqli->use_result();` or `$mysqli->store_result();` or `$mysqli->free_result();`.

But none solves the problem.
Any idea what I might be missing.

Current output - **'Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now'**

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');

$array1 = array(1 => 1000, 2 => 1564, 3 => 2646, 4 => 5462, 5 => 8974);
$array2 = array(23 => 1975, 24 => 3789, 25 => 4658, 26 => 5978, 27 => 6879);

$update1 = '';
foreach($array1 as $k => $v) {
    $update1 .= "UPDATE `ps_temp` SET `price` = {$v} WHERE `id` = {$k};";
}

$res = mysqli_multi_query($link, $update1);     // Table is updated
$error = mysqli_error($link);
echo 'Error 1 - '.$error.'<hr>';                // Output : Error 1 - 

$update2 = '';
foreach($array2 as $k => $v) {
    $update2 .= "UPDATE `ps_temp2` SET `price` = {$v} WHERE `id` = {$k};";
}

mysqli_multi_query($link, $update2);            // Table is not updated.
$error = mysqli_error($link);
echo 'Error 2 - '.$error.'<hr>';                // Output: Error 2 - 'Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now'

?>
```

Comment: If you've looked at other questions on SO, perhaps you could summarise what is different about your situation that the other questions don't have, so that people have an easier job helping you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fetch all results - for example:

```
// here: first multi query

// fetch all results
while( mysqli_more_results($link) ){
    $result = mysqli_store_result($link);
    mysqli_next_result($link);
}

// here: second multi query
```

Some SQL systems in some languages are **"lazy"**. They send query only when you ask for results (for example LINQ in C#). Maybe PHP do the same. It blocks connection waiting for your result fetching.

Comment: thanks, as my queries were just regarding update, and didn't have to store the result, hence use this shortcut `while(mysqli_more_results($link) && mysqli_next_result($link));` before executing second multi query.

Comment: I send my answer to your previous question :)